# Cannot read property length of undefined (empty container alert message)

Tags: jquery, mustache

How do I implement the code if the "matches" represents as a mustache template where in I want to return an alert message that says "no matches" and "matches are available". it works fine on the else statement, but on the if statement, it returns nothing. here is the code:

```
$.each(data.matches, function() {
               var match = this;
                if(this.matches == 0){
                    alert('no matches');
                }
                else{
                    alert('matches available');
                }
                $contents += Mustache.render(container, this);
            });
```

any ideas how? thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the data you’re iterating over? data.matches

Comment: `it returns nothing` - what does this mean, that you don't see the alert? If so, where does the error in the title of your question come into it?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand that you `data` object and inside this object list of `matches` 
it looks that when no matches it returns as `undefined` rather than empty array `[]`
so it throws exception Cannot read property length of undefined

so you have return empty array for no matches or check matches object before iterating over the list as following

```
if(!data.matches){
   alert('no matches');
}
else{
   alert('matches available');
   $.each(data.matches, function() {
          var match = this;
          $contents += Mustache.render(container, this);
   });
}
```